# Gulp browser-sync not injecting styles

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm trying to get browser-sync to inject styles using gulp. I've pretty much copied and pasted from the tutorial, but nothing happens. The sass gets compiled correctly, but the injection doesn't happen. Any ideas what I've done wrong, or how to debug this?

I'm also using MAMP if it makes any difference at all.

My Gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();



// Proxy Server
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "local.website.com"
    });

    gulp.watch('../css/source/*.scss', ['sass']);
});


// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('../css/source/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../css/build'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

The response in my console:

```
[gulp] Starting 'default'...
[gulp] Finished 'default' after 4.61 μs
[BS] Proxying: http://local.website.com
[BS] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.8.12:3000
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.8.12:3001
 -------------------------------------
[gulp] Starting 'sass'...
[BS] 1 file changed (main.css)
[gulp] Finished 'sass' after 114 ms
[gulp] Starting 'sass'...
[BS] 1 file changed (main.css)
[gulp] Finished 'sass' after 115 ms
```

If it matters, here is my package.json:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.9.11",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out this issue: https://github.com/BrowserSync/gulp-browser-sync/issues/26

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing your site using the browsersync URL and not the original one you're proxying? I tried using your gulpfile and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in my case was Drupal - it uses @import instead of link to add CSS files. This module solves it! https://www.drupal.org/project/link_css

Answer (score 0):

You say you've copy pasted from the tutorial, but you didn't copy this part that actually notifies browserSync of changes:

```
gulp.watch('../css/source/*.scss').on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

Comment: The tutorial, in fact, only uses this for when the whole HTML file changes. The styles don't use `browserSync.reload` but instead `browserSync.stream`. See http://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/#gulp-sass-css